# Show an indicator on CLI while query runs

Tags: php, command-line-interface

I have a PHP script running via CLI that's working well, but it runs a couple long queries (2-5 minutes) that would ideally give you some idea that something is still happening. When iterating through results, I do have a function running that updates the progress, but when PHP is waiting for a query to return, silence ensues.

I don't need to know anything about *when* the query will complete, but some sort of indication on the CLI that it's doing something would be a huge gain (binking `...`, or something). Possible?

Comment: Is having "This may take 5 minutes or more" printed out really not adequate enough?  How is the value being returned? Do you have multiple threads or some sort of event loop?

Comment: Q1. That's adequate enough. Still hope to see an answer to my question. Q2. The result of the query is being inserted into a different table. Q3. No, single threaded.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that using carriage returns `\r` without newlines to be extremely helpful.  They reset the output to the beginning of the line, but do not move down a line, allowing you to overwrite the current text.

Please note that you'll need to pad the line to the full length, otherwise previous characters will still linger.  For example:

```
$iteration = 0;
while (/* wait condition */) {
    printf("Process still running%-5s\r", str_repeat('.', $iteration % 5));
    sleep(1);
    $iteration++;
}
echo "\n";
echo "Task completed!";
```

If you're using a `for` loop for processing, something like this would be much more useful:

```
// Display progress every X iterations
$update_interval = 1000000;

for ($i = 0; $i < $massive_number; $i++) {
    // Do processing

    if ($i % $update_interval == 0) {
        printf("Progress: %.2f%%\r", (100 * $i / $massive_number));
    }
}
```

Comment: I have something similar to this for when there's an iteration, but if there's a single line of code that's off running a query for several minutes, is there a way to indicate that it's busy?

Comment: @Chords - Not unless you can break the single line of code into smaller chunks of code.